# What is the difference between "Fly in a city" and "Fly to a city"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

What is the difference between *fly in* and *fly to* when talking about planes going somewhere? For example:

> The plain has just flown **in** New-York.
>
> The plain has just flown **to** New-York.

I have also heard people say *fly out* not *fly from*. What is the difference between these two. For example:

> The plain flies **out**/**from** New-York at 11.

Answer (score 1):

"The plane has just flown in New York" implies a flight within the boundaries of New York. You could say that a new, experimental plane could take off, fly in a circle, and land in the same place, as having flown in a certain place.

"The plane has just flown to New York" implies a flight from somewhere to New York.

As to your last comment, "Fly out" would require a preposition after "out" - you could easily say "The plane flies out from New York [to Chicago]", or "The plane flies out to New York [from Chicago]" and mean different things.

Comment: Or, of course, 'flies **into** New York from Chicago.

Comment: What about "the flight has just flown in Heatrow airport? Does that mean thay it has landed or just within the boundaries?

Comment: Nobody would say ""the flight has just flown **in** Heatrow airport". They would use **into** as Kate Bunting wrote 17 minutes earlier.